# WSL to RPD set up / Windows 11, Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rdp, windows-11

I am trying to set up WSL to RDP, however I am getting black screen after entering my WSL credentials. Everywhere I read that I have to logout of the Ubuntu before I try to RDP, however I don't really have any running Ubuntu, I only did `wsl --install`. I am accessing everything via ESL, and if I do - `sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp start`, the RDP connections drops.

Comment: Have you considered trying the officially supported https://github.com/microsoft/wslg ? It uses your RDP under the hood and it should be easier than previous solutions.

Comment: I have a limitation, the WSL2 is from company allowed portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

going with Ubuntu 20.04 solved the iussue